# What game is this (looks like something related with House of Cards)

Tags: game-identification

I was watching some videos on YouTube and I stumbled upon this:

That guy really looks and talks like Frank Underwood, and the scene looks kind of... great. Was there any House of Cards game released?

Can anyone tell where that scene is from?

Comment: I think it's advanced warfare

Comment: Lol... I think you are right: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lP1bj1gQsDE&feature=youtu.be&t=1m30s. Post it as an answer pls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare.

Comment: He's the only reason to play that game's campaign.

Answer (score 1):

Soooo the video you have put up, just to clarify, is a collage of games. This is pretty obvious, as it also names the games as you go through, but it seems a few people are going to ignore the obvious and spit out a bunch of different game titles.

The game you are referring to is [Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Duty:_Advanced_Warfare#Plot). Good eye, though. The character your recognizing is Jonathon Irons, played by Kevin Spacey from House of Cards.

Comment: It is a collage indeed. That's why I included the timing in link (seconds 50-55). Some1 edited my question though and the screen is not representative unless you press play.

Comment: As luck has the screen you were reffering too actually came up as the splash screen.